# inset imshow within figure matplotlib

Tags: python

I'm trying to have an imshow plot inset into another in matplotlib.

I have a figure that has an plot on top and an imshow on the bottom:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
plt.imshow()
```

and then I have another figure, which also is comprised of a plot on top and an imshow below. I want this second figure to be inset into the top plot on the first figure.

I tried follow [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axes_demo.html). The code ran without an error but I had an empty axis in the position I wanted it.

My problem is just that I'm not sure where to put the plt.setp() command If that's what I am supposed to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I don't think you can put a figure into a figure in `matplotlib`. You will have to arrange your `Axes` objects (subplots) to achieve the look you want.

The example you provided uses absolute positioning to do that. `setp` there is not related to positioning, though — it just removes axis ticks from insets. An example of code that does what you want:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = numpy.linspace(0, 1)

xx, yy = numpy.meshgrid(x, x)
im = numpy.sin(xx) + numpy.cos(yy)**2


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(x, x**2)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.imshow(im)

inset1 = fig.add_axes([.15, .72, .15, .15])
inset1.plot(x, x**2)
plt.setp(inset1, xticks=[], yticks=[])

inset2 = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.55, .15, .15])
inset2.imshow(im)
plt.setp(inset2, xticks=[], yticks=[])

fig.savefig('tt.png')
```

[image]

Here the insets use explicit positioning with coordinates given in "figure units" (the whole figure has size 1 by 1).

Now, of course, there's plenty of room for improvement. You probably want the widths of your plots to be equal, so you'll have to:

- specify the positioning of all subplots explicitly; or
- play with aspect ratios; or
- use two [`GridSpec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) objects (this way you'll have the least amount of magic numbers and manual adjustment)